# Javascript - Handle function calls dynamically

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get all method calls on an object to be passed to a function that gets the function name as a string and the arguments as an array passed to it.

E.g, in pseudo code:

```
function DynamicFunctions() {
    this.tryCall = function(functionName, arguments) {
        if(functionName == "dynamic1") { console.log( "Function dynamic1" )
        else { console.log("A different function"); 
}
```

The usage is:

```
var obj = new DynamicFunctions();
obj.dynamic1();
obj.somethingElse();
```

The output in that case would be:

```
Function dynamic1
A different function
```

Comment: It seems you want [ES6 proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies). But it also seems obvious that you're facing a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Basically it would allow you to create objects whose behavior can be defined in a more dynamic away. For example, you can have an object that loads its available functions from a JSON file or create a dynamic proxy for another object functionality.

Comment: I guess I am just trying to find out if there is a mechanism in Javascript similar to [TryInvokeMember in C#](http://proq.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/more-on-dynamicobject-tryinvokemember.html). I.e - A way to handle calls to unexisting properties/functions internally.

Comment: The duplicate question has your answer.